# X days a week, X hours long rrule

Tags: rrule

I have been working with RRules to try and come up with one that includes a 3 chosen days a week working shifts that are 4 hours long each, with no end date.

This is what I could muster so far:

```
FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MO,TH,FR;BYHOUR=8,9,10,11,12;
```

My problem with this is that it produces 5 occurrences a day instead of one, four hours long, occurrence. Any suggestion on how to work this out?

Comment: Duration is irrelevant and not part of the rrule specs. Can you give an example of expected results?

Comment: I would like to have an event that could indicate a working shift that starts from 8:00am till 12:00pm. In this case it is a 5 hours working shift but you get the gest. What i came to understand from you is that the duration is  irrelevant, but how can i indicate such a thing in the calendar?